# numpy count where the difference between values bigger than something

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite new to Numpy, and I could'nt find anything meeting my requirement.

Is there any good way to do a count.where( value-value2 > threshold ) ?

I have a x,y position numpy array and I need to count the closest neighbors

Something similar to this:

`[(93, 256), (93, 256), (93, 256), (93, 257), (54, 130), (55,131)]`

I have 4 neighbours on 93/256-257 and 2 on 54-55/130-131

Comment: Your `value-value2 ` is not actually being applied to the member of the tuple but to two different tuples? Do you have a metric to get the distance between two of those tuples?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count how many occurrences:

The condition is `value1 - value0 > 100`

```
x = np.array([[93, 256], [93, 256], [93, 256], [93, 257], [54, 130], [55,   131]])
y = np.where(x[:,1] - x[:,0] > 100)
print(y[0].shape[0])
```

If you have condition on both x and y coordinates, then you can do something like this:

```
y = np.where((x[:,1] - 256 < 10) & (x[:,0] - 50 > 40))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a suitable method for calculating neighbours — [numpy.isclose(a, b, atol)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose). The following calculates neighbours within a range of 4:

```
threshold = 4
np.isclose([93, 256], [94, 256], atol=threshold)
```

The result is calculated for both points in a tuple:

```
[True,  True]
```

Maybe it will be helpful.